# How to merge all (text) files in a directory into one?

Tags: files, text-processing

I've got 14 files all being parts of one text. I'd like to merge them into one. How to do that?

Answer (score 276, accepted):

This is technically what `cat` ("concatenate") is supposed to do, even though most people just use it for outputting files to stdout. If you give it multiple filenames it will output them all sequentially, and then you can redirect that into a new file; in the case of all files just use `./*` (or `/path/to/directory/*` if you're not in the directory already) and your shell will expand it to all the filenames (excluding hidden ones by default).

```
$ cat ./* > merged-file
```

Make sure you don't use the `csh` or `tcsh` shells for that which expand the glob *after* opening the `merged-file` for output, and that `merged-file` doesn't exist before hand, or you'll likely end up with an infinite loop that fills up the filesystem.

The list of files is sorted lexically. If using `zsh`, you can change the order (to numeric, or by age, size...) with glob qualifiers.

To include files in sub-directories, use:

```
find . ! -path ./merged-file -type f -exec cat {} + > merged-file
```

Though beware the list of files is not sorted and hidden files are included. `-type f` here restricts to *regular* files only as it's unlikely you'll want to include other types of files. With GNU `find`, you can change it to `-xtype f` to also include symlinks to regular files.

With the zsh shell,

```
cat ./**/*(-.) > merged-file
```

Would do the same (`(-.)` achieving the equivalent of `-xtype f`) but give you a sorted list and exclude hidden files (add the `D` qualifier to bring them back). `zargs` can be used there to work around *argument list too long* errors.

Comment: Beware that your quoted command will probably only do what the poster wants if they're numbered in such a way that the shell expands `*` in "natural" order.  If you have "file1.txt...file9.txt...file14.txt" it won't work because file1?.txt will sort between file1.txt and file2.txt.  You'd have to rename them to "file01.txt...file09.txt...file14.txt".   Say `echo *` if you're not sure.

Comment: @Warren: good point (or you can use zsh and set its `numeric_glob_sort` option).

Comment: @warren-young a correct, useful warning comment. But in my actual case the order makes no difference (because files contain just simple SQL statements inserting data records which have no dependencies).

Comment: Beware, if the count of files exceeds a certain limit, you can run in errors like -  /bin/cat: Argument list too long

Comment: Beware that command can go wild with recursion, infinitely adding merged-file to itself. Always specify  merged-file path outside of the current dir.

Comment: @ARA1307 Only if the file already exists; otherwise the glob will be expanded before the shell opens the file to write to it. Good point in that situation though

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, this is not true for csh\tcsh. In these shells recursion happens even if resulting file doesn't exist.

Comment: I think different about `-ing` vs `-ed`. If you have a lot of files. unfortunately your system down on merging. you don't know merging or merged difference. so I recommend `cat * > merging;
mv merging merged`

Answer (score 33):

If your files aren't in the same directory, you can use the find command before the concatenation:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -name *.csv -print0 | xargs -0 -I file cat file > merged.file
```

Very useful when your files are already ordered and you want to merge them to analyze them.

---

More portably:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -name *.csv -exec cat {} + > merged.file
```

This may or may not preserve file order.

Comment: This is the way to go if you have a lot of files. You avoid an "argument list too long" error.

Comment: You need -name "*.csv" instead of -name *.csv - without the quotes it fails.

Comment: The need for quotes depends on the version of the find command, specially in find and awk it's a problem when you are on a mac, the versions of both programs is a bit old. So far on ubuntu, fedora, debian and CentOS it worked smoothly without the quotes

Comment: I would expect the unquoted version to work when there are no files in the current directory matching the pattern `"*.csv"`, since the shell would then pass the literal `*` to `find`.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 15):

The command

```
$ cat * > merged-file
```

actually has the undesired side-effect of including 'merged-file' in the concatenation, creating a run-away file. To get round this, either write the merged file to a different directory;

```
$ cat * > ../merged-file
```

or use a pattern match that will ignore the merged file;

```
$ cat *.txt > merged-file
```

Comment: `cat * > merged-file` works fine. Globs are processed before the file is created. If `merged-file` already exists, `cat` (mine at least) will detect that it's the output file and refuse to read it. IF the file already exists AND you have the redirect later in the pipeline, then it obviously can't do that, so then and only then do you get the runaway file.

Comment: `cat` has no way to detect if the file is the output one. The redirection happens in the shell; `cat` only prints on stdout.

Answer (score 11):

Like the other ones from here say... You can use `cat`

Lets say you have:

```
~/file01
~/file02
~/file03
~/file04
~/fileA
~/fileB
~/fileC
~/fileD
```

And you want only `file01` to `file03` and `fileA` to `fileC`:

```
cat ~/file01 ~/file02 ~/file03 ~/fileA ~/fileB ~/fileC > merged-file
```

Or, using brace expansion:

```
cat ~/file0{1..3} ~/file{A..C} > merged-file
```

Or, using fancier brace expansion:

```
cat ~/file{0{1..3},{A..C}} > merged-file
```

Or you can use `for` loop:

```
for i in file0{1..3} file{A..C}; do cat ~/"$i"; done > merged-file
```

Comment: Note that the string `[01-03]` won't work as a globbing pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `pattern` of a file then merge all of them as follows:

```
cat *pattern* >> mergedfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is sed:

```
sed r 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt
```

Or...

```
sed h 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt
```

Or...

```
sed -n p 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > merge.txt # -n is mandatory here
```

Or without redirection ...

```
 sed wmerge.txt 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

Note that last line write also merge.txt (not wmerge.txt!). You can use w"merge.txt" to avoid confusion with the file name, and -n for silent output.

Of course, you can also shorten the file list with wildcards. For instance, in case of numbered files as in the above examples, you can specify the range with braces in this way:

```
sed -n w"merge.txt" {1..3}.txt
```