# Why is looping over find's output bad practice?

Tags: files, find, filenames, for

This question is inspired by

[*Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice ?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22142)

I see these constructs

```
for file in `find . -type f -name ...`; do smth with ${file}; done
```

and

```
for dir in $(find . -type d -name ...); do smth with ${dir}; done
```

being used here almost on a daily basis even if some people take the time to comment on those posts explaining why this kind of stuff should be avoided...
Seeing the number of such posts (and the fact that sometimes those comments are simply ignored) I thought I might as well ask a question:

*Why is looping over `find`'s output bad practice and what's the proper way to run one or more commands for each file name/path returned by `find` ?*

Comment: I think this is sort of like "Never parse ls output!" - you can certainly do either one on a one off basis, but they're more of a quick hack than production quality. Or, more generally, definitely never be dogmatic.

Comment: More generally: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Because the point of find is to loop over what it finds.

Comment: One ancillary point -- you may want to send the output to a file, and then process it later in the script.  This way the file list is available for review if you need to debug the script.

Comment: Note, that the output of find needn't be filenames (see -print variants), so the reasoning is slightly too general. :)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

## The problem

```
for f in $(find .)
```

combines two incompatible things.

`find` prints a list of file paths delimited by newline characters. While the split+glob operator that is invoked when you leave that `$(find .)` unquoted in that list context splits it on the characters of `$IFS` (by default includes newline, but also space and tab (and NUL in `zsh`)) and performs globbing on each resulting word (except in `zsh`) (and even brace expansion in ksh93 (even if the `braceexpand` option is off in older versions) or pdksh derivatives!).

Even if you make it:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable glob (also disables brace expansion
              # done upon other expansions in ksh)
for f in $(find .) # invoke split+glob
```

That's still wrong as the newline character is as valid as any in a file path. The output of `find -print` is simply not post-processable reliably (except by using some convoluted trick, [*as shown here*](/a/67820)).

That also means the shell needs to store the output of `find` fully, and then split+glob it (which implies storing that output a second time in memory) before starting to loop over the files.

Note that `find . | xargs cmd` has similar problems (there, blanks, newline, single quote, double quote and backslash (and with some `xarg` implementations bytes not forming part of valid characters) are a problem)

## More correct alternatives

The only way to use a `for` loop on the output of `find` would be to use `zsh` that supports `IFS=$'\0'` and:

```
IFS=$'\0'
for f in $(find . -print0)
```

(replace `-print0` with `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` for `find` implementations that don't support the non-standard (but quite common nowadays) `-print0`).

Here, the correct and portable way is to use `-exec`:

```
find . -exec something with {} \;
```

Or if `something` can take more than one argument:

```
find . -exec something with {} +
```

If you do need that list of files to be handled by a shell:

```
find . -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    something < "$file"
  done' find-sh {} +
```

(beware it may start more than one `sh`).

On some systems, you can use:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -r0 something with
```

though that has little advantage over the standard syntax and means `something`'s `stdin` is either the pipe or `/dev/null`.

One reason you may want to use that could be to use the `-P` option of GNU `xargs` for parallel processing. The `stdin` issue can also be worked around with GNU `xargs` with the `-a` option with shells supporting process substitution:

```
xargs -r0n 20 -P 4 -a <(find . -print0) something
```

for instance, to run up to 4 concurrent invocations of `something` each taking 20 file arguments.

With `zsh` or `bash`, another way to loop over the output of `find -print0` is with:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file <&3; do
  something "$file" 3<&-
done 3< <(find . -print0)
```

`read -d ''` reads NUL delimited records instead of newline delimited ones.

`bash-4.4` and above can also store files returned by `find -print0` in an array with:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(find . -print0)
```

The `zsh` equivalent (which has the advantage of preserving `find`'s exit status):

```
files=(${(0)"$(find . -print0)"})
```

With `zsh`, you can translate most `find` expressions to a combination of recursive globbing with glob qualifiers. For instance, looping over `find . -name '*.txt' -type f -mtime -1` would be:

```
for file (./**/*.txt(ND.m-1)) cmd $file
```

Or

```
for file (**/*.txt(ND.m-1)) cmd -- $file
```

(beware of the need of `--` as with `**/*`, file paths are not starting with `./`, so may start with `-` for instance).

`ksh93` and `bash` eventually added support for `**/` (though not more advances forms of recursive globbing), but still not the glob qualifiers which makes the use of `**` very limited there. Also beware that `bash` prior to 4.3 follows symlinks when descending the directory tree.

Like for looping over `$(find .)`, that also means storing the whole list of files in memory¹. That may be desirable though in some cases when you don't want your actions on the files to have an influence on the *finding* of files (like when you add more files that could end-up being found themselves).

## Other reliability/security considerations

### Race conditions

Now, if we're talking of reliability, we have to mention the race conditions between the time `find`/`zsh` finds a file and checks that it meets the criteria and the time it is being used ([TOCTOU race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use)).

Even when descending a directory tree, one has to make sure not to follow symlinks and to do that without TOCTOU race. `find` (GNU `find` at least) does that by opening the directories using `openat()` with the right `O_NOFOLLOW` flags (where supported) and keeping a file descriptor open for each directory, `zsh`/`bash`/`ksh` don't do that. So in the face of an attacker being able to replace a directory with a symlink at the right time, you could end up descending the wrong directory.

Even if `find` does descend the directory properly, with `-exec cmd {} \;` and even more so with `-exec cmd {} +`, once `cmd` is executed, for instance as `cmd ./foo/bar` or `cmd ./foo/bar ./foo/bar/baz`, by the time `cmd` makes use of `./foo/bar`, the attributes of `bar` may no longer meet the criteria matched by `find`, but even worse, `./foo` may have been replaced by a symlink to some other place (and the race window is made a lot bigger with `-exec {} +` where `find` waits to have enough files to call `cmd`).

Some `find` implementations have a (non-standard yet) `-execdir` predicate to alleviate the second problem.

With:

```
find . -execdir cmd -- {} \;
```

`find` `chdir()`s into the parent directory of the file before running `cmd`. Instead of calling `cmd -- ./foo/bar`, it calls `cmd -- ./bar` (`cmd -- bar` with some implementations, hence the `--`), so the problem with `./foo` being changed to a symlink is avoided. That makes using commands like `rm` safer (it could still remove a different file, but not a file in a different directory), but not commands that may modify the files unless they've been designed to not follow symlinks.

`-execdir cmd -- {} +` sometimes also works but with several implementations including some versions of GNU `find`, it is equivalent to `-execdir cmd -- {} \;`.

`-execdir` also has the benefit of working around some of the problems associated with too deep directory trees.

In:

```
find . -exec cmd {} \;
```

the size of the path given to `cmd` will grow with the depth of the directory the file is in. If that size gets bigger than `PATH_MAX` (something like 4k on Linux), then any system call that `cmd` does on that path will fail with a `ENAMETOOLONG` error.

With `-execdir`, only the file name (possibly prefixed with `./`) is passed to `cmd`. File names themselves on most file systems have a much lower limit (`NAME_MAX`) than `PATH_MAX`, so the `ENAMETOOLONG` error is less likely to be encountered.

### Bytes vs characters

Also, often overlooked when considering security around `find` and more generally with handling file names in general is the fact that on most Unix-like systems, file names are sequences of bytes (any byte value but 0 in a file path, and on most systems (ASCII based ones, we'll ignore the rare EBCDIC based ones for now) 0x2f is the path delimiter).

It's up to the applications to decide if they want to consider those bytes as text. And they generally do, but generally the translation from bytes to characters is done based on the user's locale, based on the environment.

What that means is that a given file name may have different text representation depending on the locale. For instance, the byte sequence `63 f4 74 e9 2e 74 78 74` would be `côté.txt` for an application interpreting that file name in a locale where the character set is ISO-8859-1, and `cєtщ.txt` in a locale where the charset is IS0-8859-5 instead.

Worse. In a locale where the charset is UTF-8 (the norm nowadays), 63 f4 74 e9 2e 74 78 74 simply couldn't be mapped to characters!

`find` is one such application that considers file names as text for its `-name`/`-path` predicates (and more, like `-iname` or `-regex` with some implementations).

What that means is that for instance, with several `find` implementations (including GNU `find` on GNU systems²).

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

would not find our `63 f4 74 e9 2e 74 78 74` file above when called in a UTF-8 locale as `*` (which matches 0 or more *characters*, not bytes) could not match those non-characters.

`LC_ALL=C find...` would work around the problem as the C locale implies one byte per character and (generally) guarantees that all byte values map to a character (albeit possibly undefined ones for some byte values).

Now when it comes to looping over those file names from a shell, that byte vs character can also become a problem. We typically see 4 main types of shells in that regard:

1. The ones that are still not multi-byte aware like `dash`. For them, a byte maps to a character. For instance, in UTF-8, `côté` is 4 characters, but 6 bytes. In a locale where UTF-8 is the charset, in

   ```
    find . -name '????' -exec dash -c '
      name=${1##*/}; echo "${#name}"' sh {} \;
   ```

   `find` will successfully find the files whose name consists of 4 characters encoded in UTF-8, but `dash` would report lengths ranging between 4 and 24.
2. `yash`: the opposite. It only deals with *characters*. All the input it takes is internally translated to characters. It makes for the most consistent shell, but it also means it cannot cope with arbitrary byte sequences (those that don't translate to valid characters). Even in the C locale, it can't cope with byte values above 0x7f.

   ```
    find . -exec yash -c 'echo "$1"' sh {} \;
   ```

   in a UTF-8 locale will fail on our ISO-8859-1 `côté.txt` from earlier for instance.
3. Those like `bash` or `zsh` where the multi-byte support has been progressively added. Those will fall back to considering bytes that can't be mapped to characters as if they were characters. They still have a few bugs here and there especially with less common multi-byte charsets like GBK or BIG5-HKSCS (those being quite nasty as many of their multi-byte characters contain bytes in the 0-127 range (like the ASCII characters)).
4. Those like the `sh` of FreeBSD (11 at least) or `mksh -o utf8-mode` that support multi-bytes but only for UTF-8.

### Interrupted output

Another problem with parsing the output of `find` or even `find -print0` may arise if `find` is interrupted, for instance because it has triggered some limit or was killed for whatever reason.

Example:

```
$ (ulimit -t 1; find / -type f -print0 2> /dev/null) | xargs -r0 printf 'rm -rf "%s"\n' | tail -n 2
rm -rf "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guile/2.2/ccache/language/ecmascript/parse.go"
rm -rf "/usr/"
zsh: cpu limit exceeded (core dumped)  ( ulimit -t 1; find / -type f -print0 2> /dev/null; ) |
zsh: done                              xargs -r0 printf 'rm -rf "%s"\n' | tail -n 2
```

Here, `find` was interrupted because it reached the CPU time limit. Since the output is buffered (as it goes to a pipe), `find` had output a number of blocks to stdout and the end of the last block it had written at the time it was killed happened to be in the middle of some `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guile...` file path, here unfortunately just after the `/usr/`.

`xargs`, just saw a non-delimited `/usr/` record followed by EOF and passed that to `printf`. If the command had been `rm -rf` instead, it could have had severe consequences.

---

## Notes

¹ For completeness, we could mention a hacky way in `zsh` to loop over files using recursive globbing without storing the whole list in memory:

```
process() {
  something with $REPLY
  false
}
: **/*(ND.m-1+process)
```

`+cmd` is a glob qualifier that calls `cmd` (typically a function) with the current file path in `$REPLY`. The function returns true or false to decide if the file should be selected (and may also modify `$REPLY` or return several files in a `$reply` array). Here we do the processing in that function and return false so the file is not selected.

² GNU `find` uses the system's `fnmatch()` libc function to do the pattern matching, so the behaviour there depends on how that function copes with non-text data.

Comment: Is the bottom line that the correct way is to use `find . -exec something with {} \;` or `find . -print0 | xargs -r0 something with`? And in either case, do I need to write a function/script, called in `something with`, that contains whatever lines of code I would have included in the `for` loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 228):

> Why is looping over `find`'s output bad practice?

The simple answer is:

**Because filenames can contain *any* character.**

Therefore, **there is no printable character you can reliably use to delimit filenames.**

---

Newlines are *often* used (incorrectly) to delimit filenames, because it is *unusual* to include newline characters in filenames.

However, if you build your software around arbitrary assumptions, you at best simply fail to handle unusual cases, and at worst open yourself up to malicious exploits that give away control of your system.  So it's a question of robustness and safety.

If you can write software in two different ways, and one of them handles edge cases (unusual inputs) correctly, but the other one is easier to read, you might argue that there is a tradeoff.  (I wouldn't.  I prefer correct code.)

However, if the correct, robust version of the code is *also* easy to read, there is no excuse for writing code that fails on edge cases.  This is the case with `find` and the need to run a command on each file found.

---

Let's be more specific: On a UNIX or Linux system, filenames may contain any character except for a `/` (which is used as a path component separator), and they may not contain a null byte.

**A null byte is therefore the *only* correct way to delimit filenames.**

---

Since GNU `find` includes a `-print0` primary which will use a null byte to delimit the filenames it prints, GNU `find` *can* safely be used with GNU `xargs` and its `-0` flag (and `-r` flag) to handle the output of `find`:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 ...
```

However, there is no good *reason* to use this form, because:

1. It adds a dependency on GNU findutils which doesn't need to be there, and
2. `find` is *designed* to be able to run commands on the files it finds.

Also, GNU `xargs` requires `-0` and `-r`, whereas FreeBSD `xargs` only requires `-0` (and has no `-r` option), and some `xargs` don't support `-0` at all.  So it's best to just stick to POSIX features of `find` (see next section) and skip `xargs`.

As for point 2—`find`'s ability to run commands on the files it finds—I think Mike Loukides said it best:

> `find`'s business is evaluating expressions -- not locating files. Yes, `find` certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect.
>
> [*--Unix Power Tools*](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_12.htm)

---

### [POSIX specified uses of `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)

> What's the proper way to run one or more commands for each of `find`'s results?

To run a single command for each file found, use:

```
find dirname ... -exec somecommand {} \;
```

To run multiple commands in sequence for each file found, where the second command should only be run if the first command succeeds, use:

```
find dirname ... -exec somecommand {} \; -exec someothercommand {} \;
```

To run a single command on multiple files at once:

```
find dirname ... -exec somecommand {} +
```

---

### `find` in combination with `sh`

If you need to use *shell* features in the command, such as redirecting the output or stripping an extension off the filename or something similar, you can make use of the `sh -c` construct.  You should know a few things about this:

- **Never** embed `{}` directly in the `sh` code.  This allows for arbitrary code execution from maliciously crafted filenames.  Also, it's actually not even specified by POSIX that it will work at all.  (See next point.)
- **Don't use `{}` multiple times, or use it as part of a longer argument.**  This isn't portable.  For example, don't do this:

  <s>`find ... -exec cp {} somedir/{}.bak \;`</s>

  To quote the [POSIX specifications for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

  > If a *utility_name* or *argument* string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether *find* replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.
  >
  > ...  If more than one argument containing the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.
- The arguments following the shell command string passed to the `-c` option are set to the shell's positional parameters, **starting with `$0`**.  Not starting with `$1`.

  For this reason, it's good to include a "dummy" `$0` value, such as `find-sh`, which will be used for error reporting from within the spawned shell.  Also, this allows use of constructs such as `"$@"` when passing multiple files to the shell, whereas omitting a value for `$0` would mean the first file passed would be set to `$0` and thus not included in `"$@"`.

---

To run a single shell command per file, use:

```
find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'somecommandwith "$1"' find-sh {} \;
```

However it will usually give better performance to handle the files in a shell loop so that you don't spawn a shell for every single file found:

```
find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'for f do somecommandwith "$f"; done' find-sh {} +
```

(Note that `for f do` is equivalent to `for f in "$@"; do` and handles each of the positional parameters in turn—in other words, it uses each of the files found by `find`, regardless of any special characters in their names.)

---

**Further examples of correct `find` usage:**

(Note: Feel free to extend this list.)

- [Filter files generated by `find` by parsed output of `file` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274767/135943)
- [substring removal in find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287222/135943)
- [How to Do this List Comparison with Find?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288792/135943)
- [Using literal empty curly braces {} inside sed command from find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265898/135943)
- [How do I delete file by filename that are set as dates?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288002/135943)
- [bash: Deleting directories not containing given strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321203/135943)
- [Grep word within a file then copy the file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297006/135943)
- [Remove certain types of files except in a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275030/135943)

Comment: There's one case where I don't know of an alternative to parsing `find`'s output -- where you need to run commands *in the current shell* (e.g. because you want to set variables) for each file. In this case, `while IFS= read -r -u3 -d '' file; do ... done 3< <(find ... -print0)` is the best idiom I know. Notes: `<( )` is not portable -- use bash or zsh. Also, the `-u3` and `3<` are there in case anything inside the loop tries to read stdin.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, perhaps—but what do you need to set those variables *for*?  I would argue that whatever it is should be handled *inside* the `find ... -exec` call.  Or just use a shell glob, if it will handle your use case.

Comment: I often want to print a summary after processing files ("2 converted, 3 skipped, the following files had errors: ..."), and those counts/lists have to be accumulated in shell variables. Also, there are situations where I want to create an array of filenames so that I can do more complex things than iterate in order (in that case it's `filelist=(); while ... do filelist+=("$file"); done ...`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, the array handling seems fine so long as you **use a null byte separator** when reading/piping them—that's the major point.  The converted/skipped/error *counts* could be handled other than with shell variables.  (If you self-answer a question I'll post an alternate answer.)

Comment: Your answer is correct. However  I don't like the dogma. Even though I know better, there are many (specially interactive) use cases where it's safe and just easier to type looping over `find` output or even worse using `ls`. I'm doing this daily without problems. I know about -print0, --null, -z or -0 options of all kind of tools. But I would not waste time to use them on my interactive shell prompt unless really needed. This could be also noted in your answer.

Comment: @rudimeier, the argument on dogma vs. best practice has already been [done to death](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943).  Not interested.  If you use it interactively and it works, fine, good for you—but I'm not going to promote doing that.  The percentage of script authors who bother to learn what robust code is and then do *only that* when writing production scripts, instead of just doing whatever they're *used to doing* interactively, is extremely minimal. The handling is to *promote best practices all the time.* People need to learn that **there IS a correct way to do things.**

Comment: @GordonDavisson Why not `find ... | while IFS= read ...; do ... done`?

Comment: @immibis, because filenames can contain newlines.

Comment: @immibis: if the `while` loop is in a pipeline, bash will run it in a subshell, so variables set in it don't persist after the loop (& subshell) exits.

Comment: @immibis Actually, for cases where it's acceptable to ignore the possibility of newlines in file names, `find ... | while IFS= read -r ..; do ... done` will be slightly more rugged at the expense of having to remember to at the -r option to read. That causes read to treat backslashes in input as regular characters, not escape characters which would change the meaning of the file name.

Comment: @penguin359, if you don't have to be pure POSIX, `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d'' file; do frobnicate "${file}";done` handles any filename. But as http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/find states, -print0 isn't required by POSIX (though I see `-print0` both on FreeBSD, Ubuntu and macOS)

Comment: I give up; why does gnu xargs require -r0? Your link goes to the top of the question.

Comment: @Joshua, that comment was deleted.  I've updated the answer.  For further reading see `LESS='+/^[[:space:]]*-r' man xargs` on a Linux system.

Comment: Isn't `find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'for f do somecommandwith "$f"; done' find-sh {} +` missing a `;` before `do`: `find dirname ... -exec sh -c 'for f; do somecommandwith "$f"; done' find-sh {} +`

Comment: @AdrianPronk, Stephane Chazelas [corrected me on that point](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274767/filter-files-generated-by-find-by-parsed-output-of-file-command#comment565800_274803); actually `for f do` is *more* standard historically than `for f; do`, although the latter has just recently been accepted into POSIX.

Comment: I would have thought that the missing `;` would make the command ambiguous as the shell then has to "guess" which `do` (if there are several) starts the command-list.

Comment: @AdrianPronk no, because there is no "in."  "for f in a b c do do do echo" doesn't work, obviously.  But "for f do echo; done" is fine.  As is "for f in a b c do do; do echo."

Comment: Whoever allowed newlines to be part of filenames made an extremely bad design choice. And anyone who actually dares to use this should be excluded from the use of computers entirely. I can't think of any realistic case where it would be useful. [Rant off]

Comment: GNU coreutils added `ls --zero` (i.e., end each output line with NUL and not newline "\n")(as of 2022-06-11). See [ls source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c)


ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c
--zero                 end each output line with NUL, not newline\n\

GNU coreutils 9.1[1] Edit this on Wikidata / 15 April 2022

Answer (score 13):

*This answer is for very large result sets and concerns performance mainly, for example when getting a list of files over a slow network. For small amounts of files (say a few 100 or maybe even 1000 on a local disk) most of this is moot.*

## Parallelism and memory usage

Aside from the other answers given, related to separation problems and such, there is another issue with

```
for file in `find . -type f -name ...`; do smth with ${file}; done
```

The part inside the backticks has to be evaluated fully first, before being split on the linebreaks. This means, if you get a huge amount of files, it may either choke on whatever size limits are there in the various components; you may run out of memory if there are no limits; and in any case you have to wait until the whole list has been output by `find` and then parsed by `for` before even running your first `smth`.

The preferred unix way is to work with pipes, which are inherently running in parallel, and which also do not need arbitrarily huge buffers in general. That means: you would much prefer for the `find` to run in parallel to your `smth`, and only keep the current file name in RAM while it hands that off to `smth`.

One at least partly OKish solution for that is the aforementioned `find -exec smth`. It removes the need to keep all the file names in memory and runs nicely in parallel. Unfortunately, it also starts one `smth` process per file. If `smth` can only work on one file, then that's the way it has to be.

If at all possible, the optimal solution would be `find -print0 | smth`, with `smth` being able to process file names on its STDIN. Then you only have one `smth` process no matter how many files there are, and you need to buffer only  a small amount of bytes (whatever intrinsic pipe buffering is going on) between the two processes.  Of course, this is rather unrealistic if `smth` is a standard Unix/POSIX command, but might be an approach if you are writing it yourself.

If that is not possible, then `find -print0 | xargs -0 smth` is, likely, one of the better solutions. As @dave_thompson_085 mentioned in the comments, `xargs` does split up the arguments across multiple runs of `smth` when system limits are reached (by default, in the range of 128 KB or whatever limit is imposed by `exec` on the system), and has options to influence how many files are given to one call of `smth`, hence finding a balance between number of `smth` processes and initial delay.

EDIT: removed the notions of "best" - it is hard to say whether something better will crop up. ;)

Comment: `find ... -exec smth {} +` is the solution.

Comment: `find -print0 | xargs smth` doesn't work at all, but `find -print0 | xargs -0 smth` (note `-0`) or `find | xargs smth` if filenames don't have whitespace quotes or backslash runs one `smth` with as many filenames as available _and fit in one argument list_; if you exceed maxargs, it runs `smth` as many times as needed to handle all the args given (no limit). You can set smaller 'chunks' (thus somewhat earlier parallelism) with `-L/--max-lines -n/--max-args -s/--max-chars`.

Comment: Related: [Recursive grep vs find / -type f -exec grep {} \; Which is more efficient/faster?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/131576)

Answer (score 5):

One reason is that whitespace throws a spanner in the works, making file 'foo bar' get evaluated as 'foo' and 'bar'.

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 0 Nov  7 18:24 foo bar
$ for file in `find . -type f` ; do echo filename $file ; done
filename ./foo
filename bar
$
```

Works ok if -exec used instead

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo filename {} \;
filename ./foo bar
$ find . -type f -exec stat {} \;
  File: ‘./foo bar’
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 9109        Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/ec2-user)   Gid: (  500/ec2-user)
Access: 2016-11-07 18:24:42.027554752 +0000
Modify: 2016-11-07 18:24:42.027554752 +0000
Change: 2016-11-07 18:24:42.027554752 +0000
 Birth: -
$
```

Comment: Especially in the case of `find` since there's an option to execute a command on every file it's easily the best option.

Comment: Also consider `-exec ... {} \;` versus `-exec ... {} +`

Comment: if you use `for file in "$(find . -type f)" ` and `echo "${file}"` then it works even with whitespaces, other special characters i guess cause more trouble though

Comment: @mazs - no, quoting doesn't do what you think.  In a directory with several files try `for file in "$(find . -type f)";do printf '%s %s\n' name: "${file}";done` which should (according to you) print each file name on a separate line preceded by `name:`. It doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Looping over find's output is not bad practice—what's bad practice (in this & all situations) is *assuming* your input is a particular format instead of *knowing* (testing & confirming) it's a particular format.

tldr/cbf: `find | parallel stuff`

Answer (score 2):

Because the output of any command is a single string, but your loop needs an array of strings to loop over. The reason it "works" is that shells betrayingly split the string on whitespace for you.

Secondly, unless you need a particular feature of `find`, be aware that your shell most likely already can expand a recursive glob pattern all by itself, and crucially, that it will expand to a proper array.

Bash example:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
for i in **
do
    echo «"$i"»
done
```

Same in Fish:

```
for i in **
    echo «$i»
end
```

If you do need the features of `find`, make sure to only split on NUL (such as the `find -print0 | xargs -r0` idiom).

Fish can iterate NUL delimited output. So this one is actually *not* bad:

```
find -print0 | while read -z i
    echo «$i»
end
```

As a last little gotcha, in many shells (not Fish of course), looping over command output will make the loop body a *subshell* (meaning you can't set a variable in any way that is visible after the loop terminates), which is never what you want.

Comment: @don_crissti Precisely. It doesn't *generally* work. I was trying to be sarcastic by saying that it "works" (with quotes).

Comment: Note that recursive globbing originated in `zsh` in the early 90s (though you'd need `**/*` there). `fish` like earlier implementations of bash's equivalent feature follows symlinks when descending the directory tree though. See [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665) for the differences between the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

What's the proper way to run one or more commands for each file name/path returned by find?

I'm on a mac using zsh. I found this question while searching for how to get the results of the fd command (piping to fzf) into an array. Specifically in a way that I did not have to worry about spaces in filenames being stored as separate elements. With this array I then send those filenames to another script, one at a time.

I tried to vote up Stephane's answer because it gave me the detail I needed to find my answer - which for me was to use this:

```
array_name=(${(0)"$(fd "\.tar\.gz$|\.tgz$|\.zip$|\.tar.bz2|\.tar$" | fzf --print0)"})
```

I should probably better understand what the (${(0)...}) piece is doing. Maybe its tied to the pointing out of being able to use `IFS=$'\0'`. I tried doing a quick search and what I could find was regarding the \0. I found that here: in [the zsh documentation on Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html), where it mentions:

> #### [14.3.1 Parameter Expansion Flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)
>
> If the opening brace is directly followed by an opening parenthesis,
>   the string up to the matching closing parenthesis will be taken as a
>   list of flags. In cases where repeating a flag is meaningful, the
>   repetitions need not be consecutive; for example, ‘`(q%q%q)`’ means
>   the same thing as the more readable ‘`(%%qqq)`’. The following flags
>   are supported:
>
> [...]
>   `0`
>   Split the result of the expansion on null bytes. This is a shorthand
>   for ‘`ps:\0:`’.

Why is looping over find's output bad practice?

I'm the last person that should try and give you advice on that even after a few years of bash scripting. :) But what I have been trying to do less of is put the rc from a command that into a variable and then test the variable. Instead I try and use these types of if statements:

```
if echo “${something}” | grep '^s’ -q; then {
:
} elif [[ $(dirname \""${file}\"") == "." ]]; then {
```

I hope this helps you/someone.

Answer (score -4):

Looping over find's output is **often** bad practice, especially with general purpose scripts, where you don't know much about the circumstances, it is used.

In my daily work, I often have enough knowledge about the files below one subdirectory to exclude the possibility, that a toxic filename might be hit. And I never use filenames with blanks, newlines, tabs and such in their names on my own. It's imho a bad idea in the first place, begging for problems.

For example, I have a script to shrink images from my camera, which are generic and will never change. Their path does not contain blanks, nor the filenames. (IMG00001.JPG) If I get a new camera, I will need to change the script though.

For ad hoc commands, issued and forgotten, it's not a problem. For single user machines, if you don't share your code, it shouldn't be a problem too.

When giving advice on SO, it's often a problem when not communicating the pitfalls and assumptions you make, because other people might have a toxic filename.

Considering Linux's Gnu-find, it has 4 Options, to perform commands on files, like

```
find . -type f -name ... -exec do-smth-with {} ";"
```

and besides -exec, there is -execdir, -ok and -okdir for similar purposes. The ~dir-Versions perform the action from the directory, the file is met, in contrast to your current dir, which is recommended. The ok~-Versions ask for confirmation to perform the command.

So in allmoost all cases, you don't need a for-loop. Find iterates by itself over the results and handles blanks and the like in filenames on its own.

Terminating the command with ";" can be replaced by a plus sign without quotes, if the command, called, handles a big bunch of files as parameters gracefully.

After execution, you may even pass more options to find, like:

```
find -name "*.html" -execdir wc {} + -ls
```

to give a simple example.

I can't testify for other implementations of find.